# Unable to access project on IIS after adding to a VS solution containing other projects

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I added a new project ABC in the existing solution and trying to access that using localhost/ABC on the local IIS . Since none of the other projects have created virtual directories or converted it into application . What could be the way around for this error

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are after you need to go to the web tab on the project properties in visual studio.  This allows you to either use IIS or the Visual Studio development server.

You can specify the URL to access the projects and specific ports if you are using the local IIS.

[image: Visual Studio project properties web tab]

Comment: I am getting this error - After adding and trying to run  on IIS -- Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Comment: I can do that only after adding a virtual directory and changing it into application . But other projects in the solution are not configured as an application in IIS but working as expected --

Comment: You need an application for it to be served in IIS, if they are sub applications and should use the same session and authentication, then you can use one application at the top level.  Otherwise you can make each an application.  Did you create the directories using the create virtual directory button is Visual studio as it does the application setup